# Проблема в VS, неправильное деление

Tags: c#

Вопрос возможно глупый, не могу понять, начинаю делать число 8/30 и показывает в консоли 0, то есть отрицательных чисел нет, и десятичных тоже, в чем проблема?

```
double g = 8 / 30;
Console.Write(g);
Console.ReadKey();
```

даже такое делю, и показывает 0

[image: Вот пример]

Comment: Kisleakov  Вместо копии экрана приведите конкретный код.

Comment: вы используете целочисленное деление. Чтобы получить дробный результат от деления двух целых чисел, нужно хотябы одно явно привести к double

Comment: прочел, спасибо больше

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего так должно сработать double g = 8.0 / 30;

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо явное приведение значений.

Обратите внимание что числа 8 и 30 по умолчанию имеют тип int.

вот если бы вы сделали вот так:

```
double i = 8, j = 30;
double k = i / j;
```

Вы бы получили нужное вам значение.

В развёрнутом виде ваш пример выглядит вот так:

```
int i = 8;
int j = 30;
double k = i/j
// целочисленное / целочисленное

// Чтобы деление произвелось корректно, можно один или оба операнда явно привести к типу double
double k = (double)(i/j);
double s = (double)i/j;
```

Прочитайте про явное приведение типов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так ещё лучше и более правильно:

```
double g = 8.0 / 30.0;
```

Comment: Вы целое делите на целое, **и только потом** приводите к дробному. Целочисленное деление всё равно остаётся.